# Spring Social -ConnecController connect/twitter not initiating connection with twitter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, twitter-oauth, spring-social-twitter

I have been working on integrating my project with **twitter api**,

`connectController`, which i have declared as bean in `springsocialconfig`, is perfectly handling get requests of `/connect/twitter` that's after including **csrf** token in jsp..... but when im about to send post request from **connectTwitter.jsp** its redirecting back to **connectTwitter.jsp** page viz how many times i hit the button.
No idea whats happening background , i have set up callback url as 127.0.0.1 in app settings

I am using **Spring Mvc 4.2.5**, **Spring Security 4.0.4** , **Spring Social 1.1.2**

my springSocialConfiguration classs

```
  @Configuration
@EnableSocial
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:twitter.properties" })
public class SpringSocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

@Inject
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

//
// SocialConfigurer implementation methods
//

@Override
public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
    cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory(environment.getProperty("twitter.consumerKey"), environment.getProperty("twitter.consumerSecret")));
}

@Override
public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
    return new UserIdSource() {         
        @Override
        public String getUserId() {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (authentication == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
            }
            return authentication.getName();
        }
    };
}

@Override
public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
    return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator, Encryptors.noOpText());
}

//
// API Binding Beans
//


@Bean
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public Twitter twitter(ConnectionRepository repository) {
    Connection<Twitter> connection = repository.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class);
    return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
}


//
// Web Controller and Filter Beans
//
@Bean
public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
    ConnectController connectController = new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    return connectController;
}

@Bean
public ReconnectFilter apiExceptionHandler(UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, UserIdSource userIdSource) {
    return new ReconnectFilter(usersConnectionRepository, userIdSource);
}
```

}

my SecurityConfiguration class

```
   @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository;


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?param.error=bad_credentials").defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
            .usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password").and()
            .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
        .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/signout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/static/**", "/auth/**", "/login/**", "/signup/**","/","/home/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public TextEncryptor textEncryptor() {
        return Encryptors.noOpText();
}


    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
                "remember-me", userDetailsService, tokenRepository);
        return tokenBasedservice;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver() {
        return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    }

    @Bean(name="authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

iam getting this on my console

```
    INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Nov 24 16:11:21 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class com.twittermarketingtool.configuration.SpringSocialConfig,class com.twittermarketingtool.configuration.AppConfig,class com.twittermarketingtool.configuration.HibernateConfig]
WARN : org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - @Bean method AppConfig.propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
WARN : org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect - HHH000063: The Oracle9Dialect dialect has been deprecated; use either Oracle9iDialect or Oracle10gDialect instead
INFO : org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7affc10f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@35bcf2b2, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5b2f3e74, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@165241a7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5863f8aa, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@55794086, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@30dfc977, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6f9bdfe3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@4abc2a35, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2cdbfedf, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@468410cd, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@d813edb, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1000d825]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.AppController.loginPage()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.AppController.errorPage()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/delete-user-{userName}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.AppController.deleteUser(java.lang.String)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/edit-user-{userName}],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.AppController.updateUser(com.twittermarketingtool.model.User,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,java.lang.String)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/logout],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.AppController.logoutPage(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/signup],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.AppController.newUser(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/ || /home],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.AppController.homePage()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/signup],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.AppController.saveUser(com.twittermarketingtool.model.User,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/edit-user-{userName}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.AppController.editUser(java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/dashboard],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.AppController.profilePage(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/Access_Denied],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.AppController.accessDeniedPage(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/add_t_accounts/connect/twitter],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.TwitterIntegraionController.helloTwitter(org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/add_t_accounts],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.TwitterIntegraionController.addTwitterAccountsPage(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/twitter],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.twittermarketingtool.controller.TwitterProfileController.home(java.security.Principal,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connect(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.removeConnections(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}/{providerUserId}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.removeConnection(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[GET],params=[oauth_token]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.oauth1Callback(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[GET],params=[code]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.oauth2Callback(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[GET],params=[error]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.oauth2ErrorCallback(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connectionStatus(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connectionStatus(org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Nov 24 16:11:21 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/static/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 9448 ms
Nov 24, 2016 4:11:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Nov 24 16:11:31 IST 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 95 ms

ERROR: org.springframework.social.support.LoggingErrorHandler - Response body: {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
```

Comment: does spring security blocking authentication from twitter ?? is that possible ? i mean i almost clearly following steps from a successfully running programme

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the log output, it says "Could not authenticate you." Are you providing a password somewhere, are you sure it's correct?

Comment: I thought there is a problem with application registraion on twitter site, but after so much digging into problem i found a whitespace at end of consumerKey in properties file.